# Can I "pin" a Geode/Gemfire region to a specific subset of servers?

Tags: gemfire, geode

We make heavy use of Geode function execution to operate on data that lives inside Geode. I want to configure my cluster so functions we execute against a certain subset of data are always serviced by a specific set of servers.

In my mind, my ideal configuration looks like this: (partitioned) Region A is only ever serviced by servers 1 and 2, while (partitioned) Region B is only ever serviced by servers 3, 4, and 5.

The functions that we execute against the two regions have very different CPU/network requirements; we want to isolate the performance impacts of one region from the other, and ideally be able to tune the hardware for each server accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! When I started looking into member groups, I found this page which helped me understand the necessary configurations.
https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/99/geode/configuring/cluster_config/gfsh_config_troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, operationally that you're using `gfsh` to manage your cluster, you could use `group`s to logically segregate your cluster by assigning each server to a relevant group. Creating regions then simply requires you to also indicate which 'group' a region should be created on. Functions should already be constrained to execute against a given region with `FunctionService.onRegion()` calls.

**Note**: If you're perusing the `FunctionService` API, don't be tempted to use the `onMember(group)` methods as those unfortunately only work for peer-to-peer (server-to-server) calls. I'm assuming here that you're doing typical client-server calls. Of course, if you are doing p2p function calls then those methods would be totally relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your servers into different `groups` and then create the regions into these specific `groups`, allowing you to correctly "route" the function executions. You can get more details about this feature in [Organizing Peers into Logical Member Groups](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/99/geode/topologies_and_comm/p2p_configuration/configuring_peer_member_groups.html).

Hope this helps. Cheers.